# Importing an existing Drupal project

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-7

I am joining a team of developers who have an existing Drupal based project hosted online. So far, they have worked straight up on the production environment, meaning uploading files and making changes straight. I decided to have a development environment and have a few questions pertaining to that.

i) I have installed Drupal-7.9 on my MAC. The existing website is in Drupal 6.x. I am going to have to download the drupal files of the site onto my local drupal folder. I am assuming Drupal 7.9 will be backward compatible. Correct me if I am wrong here

ii) Now the trickier part, whilst I download the existing project onto my Drupal folder, the file directories and files are going to overwrite the existing Drupal folder, this essentially  will create unforseen issues. 
My thinking is that I should simply download these files and store them in a separate folder, and replace the installation script of the existing drupal 6.x project with that of the drupal 7.9 installation script? Not sure if this is the best strategy to go around.

This pretty much sums the challenge I am facing right now. Any light on this would be beneficial.

Thanks much,

Parijat Kalia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are trying to do requires a number of steps.

1. Firstly download the database they have online and set it up locally.
2. Setup a drupal install with the same exact version they are using on the online site
3. Download the entire sites folder from online site and replace the local site sites folder with this.
4. Go into sites/default and edit settings.php, set the base_url(note: make sure you put http:// in the base url) and database information there to your local info.
5. Now after doing all of this, visit the local site and make sure its running.
6. Now you may upgrade to drupal 7. However if the site is to be launched in drupal 6, i would not advise on upgrading, since its a lot of headache and a waste of time. This is so since drupal 6 and 7 are vastly different and upgrading may take days depending on the size of the website.

However, i wish you all the best.

Comment: Joshua, thanks much for detailing the steps and clearing my confusion. You mentioned about downloading the sites folder and replacing it with the local installation. However, what about the modules and includes that the site may have which do not come with a regular drupal install?

Comment: hey Parijat Kalia, i said to replace the LOCAL sites folder with the one from the online site. So there you would get the modules and files from the online site locally.

Comment: Hey Joshua, there seems to be a small issue. I did an sql dump of the databases on the prod environment, and installed the same version of Drupal on my local, changed the base url, and took note of the database it was connected to. 
However, while running the install.php, I mention the exact same db and the credentials, Drupal is unable to recognize this database. Also, isn't setting up a new Drupal installation going to overwrite the existing database which is the scenario given that I am downloading an existing website and setting it up locally. Do you have a solution for this? Thanks much!

Comment: hey, when you migrate a website, there is no need to run install.php. just make sure the Database string is set, and the host should be localhost, string like: $db_url = 'mysqli://user:Password@localhost/database_name'; and remember to also set the base_url and make sure it dont have a / at the end and make sure http:// is in it: $base_url = 'http://localhost/website_folder';

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid Drupal 7.x is not in any way backward compatible with Drupal 6, you'll need to install the site on your machine as a Drupal 6 site and then upgrade it to version 7.

You can view the upgrade instructions [here](http://drupal.org/node/548922)

Comment: do you think I can have 2 different DRUPAl installations on my MAMP ?

Comment: Yes you can install each site in a different sub folder, and in the `sites/default/settings.php` file for each site set the `$base_url` to e.g. `http://localhost/drupal6` and `http://localhost/drupal7` respectively